# Javascript do calculations live from textboxes

Tags: javascript

I have 3 text boxes, (`datefrom, dateto, per_day`)

I want to be able to type in these boxes and do the following calculations without having to refresh the page or submit a form:

```
dateto - datefrom = TOTAL
```

then

```
TOTAL * per_day
```

is this possible using javascript - does anyone have any examples?

I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#todate").on('keyup',function(){
        var days_amount = $(this).val() - $("#fromdate").val()
        var total = (days_amount) * $("#cost_per").val()
        $(".total_text").html(total);
})
</script>

From Date: <input type="text" name="fromdate" id="fromdate" value="10" /><br />
    To Date: <input type="text" name="todate" id="todate" value="" /><br />
    Cost Per: <input type="text" name="cost_per" id="cost_per" value="" /><br />
    <p>Total: <span class="total_text"></span></p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

but i just get the output:

```
â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹
```

Comment: Yes.  You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: Have a look at e.g. jQuery or another framework, and check the events examples.

Comment: You should learn the basics of Javascript before asking questions. Ideally start by learning plain Javascript before going into frameworks like jQuery. It's always good to know what you're dealing with. Maybe take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp or any other tutorial. You might be interested in the JS HTML DOM part as in the left navigation.

Comment: @SLaks ( +1, very funny ^^ )

Answer (score 1):

You can. As things get more complex it can help to use a framework to structure your code for this kind of auto-updating view, e.g. I like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) but there are many others.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the dates from input fields using jquery

```
$("#elementId").val()
```

convert all into date type

```
var date1 = new Date("#date1");
var date2 = new Date("#date2");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

and put the result into a new field using jquery

```
$("#result").text("value")
$("#result").html("value")
$("#result").val("value")
```

it depends from the field.